# CSS not rendered in custom template for 404 and 500 pages django 1.8

Tags: python, django

This is my folder structure

```
Music
    -Music
    -Feature
           -static
               -feature
                   core.css
                   -css
                      other css files
                   -js
                   -img  
           -templates
               404.html
               500.html
               index.html
              -feature
                  about.html
                  detail.html
                  template.html 
    manage.py
```

`views.py`

```
 from django.shortcuts import render

 def error404(request):
     return render(request,'404.html')
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [

url(r'^featured/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
url(r'^FAQ/$', views.faq, name='faq'),
]
handler404 = 'mysite.views.error404'
```

The custom 404.html file gets rendered but with no css.And normally the css works fine on other pages but when I set `debug=false`to check the custom 404 error page in `settings.py` the css for the entire project disappears. Something to do with folder structure or some other problem? 
edit: `core.css` is the main css file and the part with `other css files` contains css for plugins

Comment: Your handler404 and view are okay. But you don't need them. Just a custom 404 template is enough.

Answer (score 3):

It's about serving static files. When you use `DEBUG = True` then django takes care about them otherwise your server should do it. Django in debug mode uses this [view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve). The warning from there:

> This view will only work if DEBUG is True.
>
> That’s because this view is grossly inefficient and probably insecure.
>   This is only intended for local development, and should never be used
>   in production.

You can run your server with `--insecure` [option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-option---insecure) just to test 404 error or you can explicilty create url for that page to check its styling:

> Use the **--insecure** option to force serving of static files with the
>   staticfiles app even if the DEBUG setting is False. By using this you
>   acknowledge the fact that it’s grossly inefficient and probably
>   insecure. This is only intended for local development, should never be
>   used in production and is only available if the staticfiles app is in
>   your project’s INSTALLED_APPS setting. runserver --insecure doesn’t
>   work with CachedStaticFilesStorage.

Answer (score 1):

Your handler404 and view are okay. But you don't need them. Just a custom 404 template is enough. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception

> In order to use the Http404 exception to its fullest, you should
>   create a template that is displayed when a 404 error is raised. This
>   template should be called 404.html and located in the top level of
>   your template tree.

The template is in the right location. I think the problem is serving your static files. Open developer tools in your browser to see what resources fail to load (console, network or sources tab). Inspect the paths. Is there an external style sheet link in the head section of the 404 source? (elements tab or view source code).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/